# jquery document.ready cross-browser behavior with images

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

So, briefly describing the model first.

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

Say, we have few `<div>` blocks, each containing some image with variable dimensions.
And suppose, after the page loads, we need to make some operations with those `<div>`s.
For example, move them to the right by their own width minus 200px.
Or anything else, that needs the values of those dimensions.

The main idea is to get the image `width` and then `.animate()` the `left` property of a `div` by a required value. But the code like --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Img = $('img');
$('div').animate({'left': parseInt(Img.css('width'))-200}, 2000);
})
```

--  behaves differently in various browsers.

FF gets the width of an image correctly, also IE and Opera do.
But Safari says the `width` is `0px`. Chrome fails at about 6 of 10 page reloads.

I understand that this behavior is not a failure, because actually at document.ready() only DOM is loaded, while image container still has dimensions equal to zero. *But why the behavior differs then? And who is right in this case?*

So, I have to fire those operations only when image is loaded.
But if I have several such `<div>`s, how can I check that all images (of this kind) has been loaded?
Or the best way here is just to use `$(window).load`?

http://jsfiddle.net/nqmc9/2/light/ - fiddle doesn't show the real problem, because output page fires the result on `window.load`. So here you can just see the main idea.
I could not find any free hosting to put there plain HTML - btw, **are there such simple services**.

 So just pasting code here - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uMhXkDMB - and here...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                border: 1px solid;
            }
            img {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p></p>
        <div>
            <img src="http://fb.ru/misc/i/gallery/10881/25071.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var Img = $('img');
                $('p').html(
                    Img[0].tagName+ ': ' + 
                    Img.css('width')+' * '+
                    Img.css('height')
                );
                $('div').animate({'left': parseInt(Img.css('width'))-200}, 2000);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try it in various browsers over and over, you'll likely see different behavior on the first try than you do on subsequent tries.

Comment: As far as fiddle, you can recreate it in fiddle by changing the dropdown from onload to nowrap in body.

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) helps? or you could load your images via javascript and use the .load() event listener

Comment: `.on('load'` would be more appropriate, since `.load()` is an ajax helper not a load event.

Comment: For not cached image, looks like FF doesn't return accurate size image too; Check it there: http://jsfiddle.net/RWLD6/  `ctrl+F5` to refresh and clear cache

Comment: Didn't know of that option, it is the very thing i needed, vn.
And caching is the answer to "Why so different"
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the width of an image that is not loaded yet. You have two options. Use the window onload event, or use an onload event on each individual image.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var Img = $('img');
    $('p').html(
        Img[0].tagName+ ': ' + 
        Img.css('width')+' * '+
        Img.css('height')
    );
    $('div').animate({'left': parseInt(Img.css('width'))-200}, 2000);
})
```